# Do reverse-thread eye screws exist?

Tags: screws, fence, steel

I know I can't ask shopping questions, but please bear with me.

I don't want to purchase turnbuckles for my wire rope fence, so I want to use what someone here suggested: use a reverse-threaded screw eye on one post and a regular eye screw on the other. Then I tighten both without affecting the rope.

So I already have the [size 104 screw eyes](https://www.boltdepot.com/Product-Details.aspx?product=15472), but I'm having trouble finding that same screw eye, but reverse-threaded.

I've called many businesses (both retail and online) and nobody seems to have them. Is this an item that does not exist?

Comment: They only exist as part of turnbuckles AFAIK; and they are *eye bolts*, not screw eyes, meaning they have a machine thread not a wood screw type thread.

Comment: If I can't find them at McMaster-Carr (and I can't) odds are quite low, as they have a very extensive selection, though they are often not the lowest cost. The closest thing I CAN find is a "blank" eyebolt, which you could then thread with a left-hand die and purchase matching left-hand huts for. Alternatively you could make the whole thing yourself, starting with a rod and using a bender to make the loops, then threading then shank to suit.

Comment: Thanks. I called McMaster and they don't have them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a left hand threaded eye screw on one end of a cable and a right handed screw eye on the other end is an OK theoretical solution. However in practice it is nearly impractical because to avoid twisting the cable you have to tighten one may be a quarter turn and then run to the other end and turn it the opposite direction quarter turn.

If you want to avoid turn buckles then you best realistic solution is to just use a regular screw eye to secure the cable on one end. Then use a threaded eye bolt on the other end that has a long threaded end that passes completely through the post. Afix the cable to the eye and then simply tighten using a using a regular nut and washer in the threaded end of the eye bolt. This way you can get a consistent look of the cable terminations but have proper provision for re-tightening the cable at a later date.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm going to do. I was considering that possibility but wasn't sure if it was possible. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use your computers search engine to find the following: I used "GOOGLE".  1) Cable Bullet System. 2)Deck cable railing systems on Amazon.  3) Swageless lag screws terminals. This will give you some ideas from many different sources.